# Hypergeometric Equations & Series

Tags: complex-analysis, hypergeometric-function

The question states:

Show that $F\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4};1;4z(1-z)\right)$ satisfies the hypergeometric equations satisfied by $F\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};1;z\right)$.

Show that, in the left-hand of the lemniscate $\vert z(1-z)\vert =\frac{1}{4}$, these two functions are equal; and in the right hand-side of the lemniscate, the former function is equal to $F\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};1;1-z\right)$.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Where are you having difficulties? For the first question, it suffices to write the diff. equation for $F(\frac14,\frac14;1;w)$, make the change of variables $w=4z(1-z)$ and compute the transformed equation (containing derivatives wrt $z$).